# How to call child component function from Parent in react

Tags: reactjs

How to call child component function from Parent in react

on click of button need to call child function needToBeCalled() from parentComponent

please refer below snippet

```
class Parent {

render(){
return(
<button onClick={() => }>Click</button>
<Child />
)
}
}

class Child {
function needToBeCalled() {

}
render(){
return (

)
}
}
```

Comment: This is not a recommended pattern in React, as the idea is to be declarative based on data being passed down. So the framework itself makes this rather difficult to do by design. Can you reframe this so that instead of calling a function you are passing data down to the child via its props? Or can you move the button to be in the child component itself? A very common pattern is to have a button in a child call a callback function passed in via props, that may be a better pattern for your use case. Or you may simply keep the button in the Child entirely if the parent doesn't need to know.

Comment: In this scenario, i dont want to send data to child,instead need to call the function in child from parent

Comment: It's not recommended. But good luck. You can do it with refs like someone commented below, but the official react docs [caution against this mindset](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs) for good reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's antipattern  in React, but you can use ref to do something like so

---

```
  class Parent {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.myRef = React.createRef();
   }
  render(){
     return(
      <button onClick={this.myRef.current}>Click</button>
      <Child myRef={this.myRef}/>
    )
   }
  }

  class Child {
    componentDidMount(){
      function needToBeCalled() {

    }
    this.props.myRef.current = needToBeCalled
  }
  render(){
   return (

    )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but there is an alternative to succeed what you wanna do.

The alternative is to use in the Child component, a react life cycle called componentDidUpdate() and get the props which have changed.

For example

```
class Parent extends React.PureComponent {
    state={
        trigger:false
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <button onClick={() => {this.setState(prevState=>({trigger:!prevState.trigger}))}}>Click</button>
        <Child trigger={this.state.trigger} />
        )
    }
}

class Child extends React.PureComponent {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.props.trigger && prevProps.trigger !== this.props.trigger) { // <---- When the props trigger turns true, we are good to go
            this.needToBeCalled() // <---- You do trigger your function right now kid
        }
    }
    function needToBeCalled() {

    }
    render(){
        return (

        )
    }
}
```