# how can i access the inside property (title) of an component in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I want to access the title property outside the return so that I can pass it to others but I don't know how to access the property of a component
here is my custom component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
export const ClickableIcon = (props) => {
    console.warn('hi')
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} >
            <Text>{props.title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

here I am using that component

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, } from 'react-native';
const Divisions = (props) => {
console.warn(title) **I want to access particular title of key 1** 
  return (
    <View style={styles.block}>

      <ClickableIcon  onPress={props.onPress} title='ac service' key='1'
       />
      <ClickableIcon onPress={props.onPress}  title='babysitter' key='2' 
       />

    </View>
  )
}
export default Divisions;
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question

Comment: You should add more details. Which property you want to access and from where ? Add a proper description otherwise no one will be able to fully understand the issue. All I can do right now is making assumptions.

Comment: sorry I am new in stack overflow, now I have learnt to format the problem a Lil bit also edited my recent problem as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to access `title` prop of child component in his father, while the first moment you declaring the values for `title` is at the render of the child.

So you got two options,

The first is to use `ref` to access the property of a child at the father. The upside of this approach is you still can declare title only at the render, the downside is it complex, antipattern, and React docs recommend against

[How to call child component function from Parent in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61734117/how-to-call-child-component-function-from-parent-in-react/61734471#61734471)

The second option is to declare `titles` before the render, and render a map for this array

---

```
   const Divisions = (props) => {
      const titles = [ { t: 'ac service', k: 1 }, { t: 'babysitter', k: '2' } ]
      return (
        <View style={styles.block}>
         { titels.map(title => 
            <ClickableIcon onPress={props.onPress} title={title.t} key={title.k} />
          )
         }
        </View>
        )
       }
```

---

now `titels` are exist at parent