# How to Open Dialog Component from Parent?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, headless-ui

I need to be able to open a Headless UI Dialog component from its parent. How do I accomplish this?

[image: Trigger Headless UI Dialog Component from Parent]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger child component function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65581881/how-to-trigger-child-component-function)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65582073/1418750

Comment: No, I'm not looking to conditionally show/hide the modal component. I'm looking to trigger the native open/close state in the child ModalStandard component from the parent Playground component.

Comment: Did you actually check out the link? Because there is nowhere it talks about 'conditionally show/hide the modal component'.

Comment: Yeah I did. It was just use effect hooks to toggle an element based on the visible property. It had nothing to do with how to accomplish what I’m trying to accomplish with Headless UI. At least not that I could figure out! 

Comment: Then your question is not clear

Answer (score -1):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ModalStandard from "./components/modals/ModalStandard";

const Playground = () => {
  const [isTriggered, setIsTriggered] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      {isTriggered && (<ModalStandard isOpen={true}>This is my standard modal.</ModalStandard>)}
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {setIsTriggered(true);}}
          className="cursor"
        >
          open Modal
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Playground;
```

onClick of the open Modal button -> set a state variable to true, which tracks if button is clicked to render the component conditionally, for conditional rendering : use && operator , which renders the right hand side component only if left hand side of the operator evaluates to true[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbkdk.png)

Comment: I'm not looking to conditionally show/hide the modal component. I'm looking to trigger the native open/close state in the child ModalStandard component from the parent Playground component.

Comment: try creating a method/function  in child ModalStandard component which can change the state and  Create a reference for the child component in parent component using React.createRef() then Attach reference with the child component using ref={}.
Call the child component method using this.your-reference.current.method.